# Remove Actions added by SEO ultimate Plugin

Tags: filters

I am trying to remove the action hooks added by SEO ultimate plugin for some pages. The way it is added in the plugin's class is

```
    //Hook to output all <head> code i changed the priority to 2
    add_action('wp_head', array(&$this, 'template_head'), 2);
```

The SEO plugin creates a global variable like this

```
global $seo_ultimate;
    $seo_ultimate =& new SEO_Ultimate(__FILE__);
```

In my plugin, i try removing it by

```
add_action('wp_head',array($this, 'remove_seo_header'),1);

    }
    function remove_seo_header() {

         remove_action('wp_head', array($seo_ultimate,'template_head'));
}
```

But it does not remove the action. Can anyone point out where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the same priority, and you need access to the global variable:

```
function remove_seo_header() {

    remove_action(
        'wp_head', 
        array( $GLOBALS['seo_ultimate'], 'template_head' ), 2 
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also foreach through the registered hooks like this:

```
function remove_filter_in_class( $tag, $function_to_remove, $priority, $class ) {
    if ( isset( $GLOBALS['wp_filter'][ $tag ][ $priority ] ) ) {
        foreach ( $GLOBALS['wp_filter'][ $tag ][ $priority ] as $key => $function ) {
            if ( is_array( $function['function'] )
                && $function_to_remove === array_pop( $function['function'] )
                && $class === get_class( array_pop( $function['function'] ) )
            ) {
                return remove_filter( $tag, $key, $priority );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/lgedeon/7806513f47b6466fc2cb